# Book series about the threat of aliens coming out of the void

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

I am trying to find a sci fi series of books I borrowed from the library, prior to 2005, about the threat of aliens coming out of the void.

A high-ranking military man kidnaps his former lover, I think to gain her assistance, and there is a second storyline about a hidden child.  If I remember correctly, every book cover shows the military man and the woman he kidnapped on the bridge of a space ship.